# Concatenate 2 STL vectors in constant O(1) time

Tags: c++, stl, point-cloud-library

I'll give some context as to why I'm trying to do this, but ultimately the context can be ignored as it is largely a classic Computer Science and C++ problem (which must surely have been asked before, but a couple of cursory searches didn't turn up anything...)

I'm working with (large) real time streaming point clouds, and have a case where I need to take 2/3/4 point clouds from multiple sensors and stick them together to create one big point cloud. I am in a situation where I do actually need all the data in one structure, whereas normally when people are just visualising point clouds they can get away with feeding them into the viewer separately.

I'm using Point Cloud Library 1.6, and on closer inspection its [PointCloud class](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/375741a0a30a5680bebe499c9bb2cc2ec988e201/common/include/pcl/point_cloud.h) (under `<pcl/point_cloud.h>` if you're interested) stores all data points in an STL vector.

Now we're back in vanilla CS land...

PointCloud has a += operator for adding the contents of one point cloud to another. So far so good. But this method is pretty inefficient - if I understand it correctly, it 1) resizes the target vector, then 2) runs through all Points in the other vector, and copies them over.

This looks to me like a case of O(n) time complexity, which normally might not be too bad, but is bad news when dealing with at least 300K points per cloud in real time.

The vectors don't need to be sorted or analysed, they just need to be 'stuck together' at the memory level, so the program knows that once it hits the end of the first vector it just has to jump to the start location of the second one. In other words, I'm looking for an O(1) vector merging method. Is there any way to do this in the STL? Or is it more the domain of something like std::list#splice?

Note: This class is a pretty fundamental part of PCL, so 'non-invasive surgery' is preferable. If changes need to be made to the class itself (e.g. changing from vector to list, or reserving memory), they have to be considered in terms of the knock on effects on the rest of PCL, which could be far reaching.

**Update:** I have filed an issue over at PCL's GitHub repo to get a discussion going with the library authors about the suggestions below. Once there's some kind of resolution on which approach to go with, I'll accept the relevant suggestion(s) as answers.

Comment: This isn't possible from what I know. Why don't you reserve your vector to a large capacity you're comfortable with?

Comment: I know C++, C, and C#. But what is CS?

Comment: OP means Computer Science, I think.

Comment: @user1475135: vectors rarely resize, even with `+=`.  If it's actually a `std::vector`, then don't worry about it, it's not your issue.

Comment: It's _potentially_ possible to non-invasively reserve memory simply by pushing back `N` points when it's created, and then deleting them all.

Comment: Is it possible for you to convince your several sources to all dump points into a single vector in the first place?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A vector is *not* a list, it represents a sequence, but with the additional requirement that elements must be stored in contiguous memory. You cannot just *bundle* two vectors (whose buffers won't be contiguous) into a single vector without moving objects around.

Answer (score 6):

This problem has been solved many times before such as with String Rope classes.

The basic approach is to make a new container type that stores pointers to point clouds. This is like a std::deque except that yours will have chunks of variable size. Unless your clouds chunk into standard sizes?

With this new container your iterators start in the first chunk, proceed to the end then move into the next chunk. Doing random access in such a container with variable sized chunks requires a binary search. In fact, such a data structure could be written as a distorted form of B+ tree.

Answer (score 5):

There is no vector equivalent of splice - there can't be, specifically because of the memory layout requirements, which are probably the reason it was selected in the first place.

There's also no constant-time way to concatenate vectors.

I can think of one (fragile) way to concatenate *raw arrays* in constant time, but it depends on them being aligned on page boundaries at both the beginning and the end, and then re-mapping them to be adjacent. This is going to be pretty hard to generalise.

There's another way to make something that *looks like* a concatenated vector, and that's with a wrapper container which works like a deque, and provides a unified iterator and `operator[]` over them. I don't know if the point cloud library is flexible enough to work with this, though. (Jamin's suggestion is essentially to use something like this *instead of* the vector, and Zan's is roughly what I had in mind).

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't concatenate two vectors by a simple link, you actually have to copy them.

However! If you implement move-semantics in your element type, you'd probably get significant speed gains, depending on what your element contains. This won't help if your elements don't contain any non-trivial types.
Further, if you have your vector reserve way in advance the memory needed, then that'd also help speed things up by not requiring a resize (which would cause an undesired huge new allocation, possibly having to defragment at that memory size, and then a huge memcpy).

Barring that, you might want to create some kind of mix between linked-lists and vectors, with each 'element' of the list being a vector with 10k elements, so you only need to jump list links once every 10k elements, but it allows you to dynamically grow much easier, and make your concatenation breeze.

```
std::list<std::vector<element>> forIllustrationOnly; //Just roll your own custom type.

index = 52403;

listIndex = index % 1000
vectorIndex = index / 1000

forIllustrationOnly[listIndex][vectorIndex] = still fairly fast lookups
forIllustrationOnly[listIndex].push_back(vector-of-points) = much faster appending and removing of blocks of points.
```

Answer (score 2):

You will not get this scaling behaviour with a vector, because with a vector, you do not get around the copying. And you can not copy an arbitrary amount of data in fixed time.

I do not know PointCloud, but if you can use other list types, e.g. a linked list, this behaviour is well possible. You might find a linked list implementation which works in your environment, and which can simply stick the second list to the end of the first list, as you imagined.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Boost range joint at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/join.html

This will take 2 ranges and join them. Say you have vector1 and vector 2.

You should be able to write

```
auto combined = join(vector1,vector2).
```

Then you can use combined with algorithms, etc as needed.

Answer (score 0):

No O(1) copy for vector, ever, **but**, you should check:

- Is the element type trivially copyable? (aka `memcpy`)
- Iff, is my `vector` implementation leveraging this fact, or is it stupidly looping over all 300k elements executing a trivial assignment (or worse, copy-ctor-call) for each element?

What I have seen is that, while both `memcpy`as well as an assignment-for-loop have O(n) complexity, a solution leveraging `memcpy` can be much, much faster.

So, the problem *might* be that the vector implementation is suboptimal for trivial types.